# jrecordbind - XSD for mainframe packed decimals

Tags: java, cobol, mainframe, copybook

I started using `jrecordbind` to convert COBOL data to Java using a `copybook`. I saw the basic [example here](http://jrecordbind.org/).

1. Noticed, `xs:float` is used for floating point values. Some of my COBOL output fields are in `COMP-3` and some are in `COMP` packed decimals. How do I mention this in the XSD?
   `<xs:element name="oneFloat" type="xs:float" jrb:length="3" jrb:converter="it.assist.jrecordbind.test.SimpleRecordFloatConverter"/>`
2. My `COBOL` data is in EBCDIC encoding, is there any way to tell `jrecordbind` about this? so that later in Java I can use required encoding ("Cp1047" for example) to get values.

Comment: "JRecordBind is useful in any situation where data must be transferred between a bean-based application and an application that can read and write **text files**. The latter application might be, for example, a legacy operational business platform, that can write out or read in data records in the form of fixed field text data dumps, or write data into formatted text reports." If you are doing as previously suggested, you don't have to worry about COMP-3 or COMP. The type= presumably refers to how you use it in your program, not on the **text** file.

Comment: Note, I thought you were looking at http://jrecord.sourceforge.net/?